# Hacer procedimiento almacenado con recorrido de otra tabla

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedure

Buenas tardes comunidad. Soy principiante en esto de los procedimientos almacenados, y quisiera saber alguna manera para hacer lo siguiente:

Tengo estas 2 tablas:

**Saldos**

```
saldoid|cuentaid|deudas|abonos|mes
-------+--------+------+------+---
   1   |    1   | 2000 | 1000 | 1
   2   |    2   | 3000 | 100  | 1
   3   |    5   | 100  | 50   | 1
   4   |    3   | 200  | 120  | 2
   5   |    6   | 40   | 40   | 2
   6   |    4   | 2304 | 2100 | 3
```

**Cuentas**

```
cuentaid|cuenta |deudas01|abonos01|deudas02|abonos02|deudas03|haber03
--------+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------
    1   |1020319|  2000  |  1000  |     0  |     0  |     0  |   0   
    2   |1823934|  3000  |   100  |     0  |     0  |     0  |   0
    3   |1238923|   100  |    50  |     0  |     0  |     0  |   0
    4   |2389235|     0  |     0  |   200  |   120  |     0  |   0
    5   |9583313|     0  |     0  |    40  |    40  |     0  |   0
    6   |1223940|     0  |     0  |     0  |     0  |  2304  |   0
```

Lo que necesito hacer es un procedimiento almacenado, que haga un recorrido en la tabla cuentas, para sacar todas las *cuentas.cuentaid*, y seguido de esto, agregar deudas/abonos por *saldos.cuentaid*.

NOTA: Ya tengo parte del procedimiento almacenado, quisiera saber como hacer el recorrido y agregar *cuentas.cuentaid*.

Comment: Hola pudieras recorrer mas bien la tabla Saldos y operar deudas/abonos desde alli y finalmente agregar ese resultado dentro de una tabla si deseas, ya que la suma de las deudas y de los abonos la contemplas en saldos, ¿Me explico? ¿Es lo que buscas?

Comment: Gracias por la resputesta. Pero necesito que sea de la tabla de cuentas, porque hay cuentas que no tienen saldo. Alguna idea de como hacer una variable, la cual contenga el valor (de una en una) de todas las cuentas?

Que valga cuentaid = 1,2,3,4,5,6... etc

Comment: Y este procedimiento almacenado o la solución que sea, ¿conoce de antemano las columnas de la tabla `Cuentas`? Porque si es necesario analizar la tabla y construir la query "al vuelo" la solución es mucho más complicada que conociendo los campos

Comment: Un amigo me ayudó con la duda, aprecio sus soluciones. Finalmente lo hice con cursores sobre un Loop :)

Gracias por sus soluciones. Buen día.